# Retrieve and display results of jQuery GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, get

I'm trying to retrieve and display data from the ESV API: http://www.esvapi.org/

It's working on the codecademy.com domain but not the esvapi.org domain. 

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryAcid/yqCcn/

```
<input type="button" value="get data" id="btn" >

$("#btn").click(function() {

    var response = '';
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
        // url: "http://www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?key=IP&passage=John+1",
        url: "http://www.codecademy.com/",
        async: false,
        success : function(text)
        {
         response = text;
        }
    });

    document.write(response);

});
```

Comment: Try adding the following to your Ajax call: dataType:"jsonp"

Comment: Maybe you need credentials or just adjust the headers..

Comment: You can not use document.write after the page loads. It does nasty things like replaces all the pages content. If you are debugging, use the console.

Comment: Please try the Fiddle before commenting. It works right now on one domain. I just need to find out why it's not working on another domain. The document.write is fine in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryAcid/qDrw8/1/

```
<input type="button" value="get data" id="btn" >

$("#btn").click(function() {
reference='Jhon+1'
$.getJSON('http://www.esvapi.org/crossref/ref.php?reference=' + reference + '&callback=?',
    function(text){
        if(text){
            $('body').html(text.content);
        } else {
            $('body').html('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i Tried the fiddle example but did not work with the first or the second URL's, The problem is related to the cross domain calls, you can not call directly to a service that is not on your own domain unless you are using jsonp or setting some headers in your servers explicitly allowing cross domain calls(this technique wont work in IE)

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Yahoo Query Language (YQL). See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryAcid/jbCuH/1/

```
<input type="button" value="get data" id="btn">

$("#btn").click(function () {
var response = '';
var url = "http://www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?key=IP&passage=John+1";
var yql = "select content from data.headers where url='" + url + "'";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + encodeURIComponent(yql) + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=?",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        response = data.query.results.resources.content;
        document.write(response);
    }
});

});
```